# QML chartview get X,Y of Lineseries.onPointAdded

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qchartview

How can I get the X and Y of the point added in `Lineseries`?

This code is placed inside a simple `ChartView`.

If I have the following:

```
LineSeries {
        id: data
        name: "name"
        axisX: axisX
        axisY: axisY
        onPointAdded: {
            //retrieve x and y
    }
}
```

What should replace the comment inside `onPointAdded`?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`pointAdded`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtcharts-xyseries.html#pointAdded-signal) signal passes as a parameter the `index` of the added element, this index must be used next to the method [`at()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtcharts-xyseries.html#at-method) to obtain the point:

```
onPointAdded: {
    var point = data.at(index);
    console.log(point.x, point.y)
}
```